# Payment - Android in-app purchases

Tags: payment, gateway, billing, in-app

I plan to use a 3rd party payment gateway for in-app purchases for an app distributed through the Google PlayStore. I'm aware of Google's policies regarding payments for in-app purchases (https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/)

My content / service delivery model is as follows:

When a user pays for a plan he gets—

1. Certain features in the app
2. Certain features in our web portal, completely outside the app
3. Our deployment staff going and visiting the user's location and
   providing training and setup services.
4. For some plans, we will be delivering a physical device to user's
   locations (a POS machine to accept card payments)

Since my offerings are a combination of physical and digital goods and services provided within and outside the app, it does not clearly fall under the categories Google mentions in the link above.

My question is: Can I use a 3rd party payment gateway to accept payments within the app given my content / service delivery model? 
Do I risk being blacklisted? Does Google give a time window to react by sending an email first before pulling apps down.

I know my question is similar to this one: [Android In-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113796/android-in-app-purchases?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I'd like to get similar opinions on my planned content / service delivery model.
Kindle PlayStore app, distributed via Play Store also seems to be an example of an app using different payment method from Google's billing APIs